# escape single quotes in the string templates when env variables are passed to psql

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker

I'm passing env variables from .env file to my bash script and I want to run psql command. Unfortunatelly I'm struggling with a correct string template so my psql always fails.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o allexport
source .env

if [[ $SHOULD_UPDATE_CONTENT==1 ]]
then
  # 1. Truncate all the tables before inserting data
  r="select $DB_SCHEMA.truncate_tables('user','$DB_SCHEMA');"
  docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME psql -U dev -d data -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -c "${r}"
fi

set +o allexport
```

.env

```
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=dbTest
DB_SCHEMA=schema
SHOULD_UPDATE_CONTENT=1
```

Comment: This is almost impossible to do safely using shell commands.  (The script you show is vulnerable to both SQL- and shell-injection attacks, and if the attacker knows `docker` is available, they can use that to root the host.)  Can you use a higher-level language with an SQL client library, connecting to the database's published ports without using `docker exec`?

Comment: Note that your if condition is **always true**. `[[` and `[` do different things depending on _how many (whitespace-separated) arguments_ they receive. If there's just a single argument, then the result is "true" if the argument **is not empty**. `$SHOULD_UPDATE_CONTENT==1` is always non-empty, regardless of the value of the variable. You need spaces around `==`

Comment: Doubling the single quotes can be accomplished with `"${r//\'/\'\'}"`, but heed David's excellent advice.

Comment: @glennjackman ok, did it, and now my script is always not running, any ideas?

Comment: I just don't see CONTAINER_NAME variable in your `.env`. I checked on my PC and single quote still be passed to psql, and psql return value normally. Why does your single quote need to be escape?

Comment: I can't see what changee, so how am I supposed to have any idea how to fix it?